# Single code issue in SQL at the time of compilation

Tags: java, sql, compilation, escaping

I write a SQL

```
SELECT ID                                   
FROM NDA.K_FAKTURIER_KDF                    
WHERE FAKTURIER_KDF_KZ = ?                  
AND NVL(MANDANT, ' ') = (CASE ?             
WHEN '01180311' THEN                        
'BUTLERS'                                   
ELSE                                        
' '                                         
END)
```

In my program when I run it I got error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
```

At the time of debug I found that Java compiler execute query like

```
SELECT ID                                   
FROM NDA.K_FAKTURIER_KDF                    
WHERE FAKTURIER_KDF_KZ = ?                  
AND NVL(MANDANT, ' ') = (CASE ?             
WHEN 01180311 THEN                      
'BUTLERS'                                   
ELSE                                        
' '                                         
END)`
```

So Java compiler escape single code so can any one tell me how it will run properly?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the character? WHEN \'01180311\' THEN

Comment: please post the code (atleast the relevant parts) ..

Comment: Is MANDANT a character or numeric field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using a PreparedStatement, and pass in "01180311" as a setString parameter?

Comment: +1 Yes! Let the JDBC driver figure out the correct syntax for the data type and how to put the parameter into the query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MANDANT is a character field, then performing a character-only operation on the `'01180311'` value might prevent the compiler stripping out the quotes.

Try changing `'01180311'` to `'0118'||'0311'` in your expression.